# What is best practice about deleting data in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to delete over millions of data in MongoDB using PyMongo with pyspark.

So, I need some best practice to delete bulk data from MongoDB

I think below

First, Collect the data from HDFS with spark dataframe. (ex, df.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect())

Second, Put all data from first to 'list' variable. and create query to mongo like " { "_id" : { "$in": list }} "

Third. Use function "delete_many()" to delete the list like "{db}.{collection}.delete_many(query)

But, I think it looks bad practice because it look some problem the size of the list

Do i cut the list thousand of list and execute?

**what is the best practice in this situation..?**

are there any other practice?

Comment: To delete many documents based upon a query filter, and with a single method, use`collection.delete_many()`. Alternatively, you can use the `collection.bulk_write`method - this allows batching the delete operation when there are a large number of documents to be deleted.

Comment: @prasad_ you mean "collection.buldWrite([{ deleteMany : list }])"? thank you I'll try it

Comment: Refer this from MongoDB docs: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#deleteone-and-deletemany